# Studying in EU as EU citizen without EU passport

Tags: germany, dual-nationality, study, new-zealand, czech-republic

My daughter wants to study in Germany for 6 months through a student exchange programme. She has dual citizenship - Czech Republic (EU) and New Zealand (non-EU), however she only has NZ passport, her CZ one has expired a long time ago.

As a *Czech* citizen she could go study in Germany without any restrictions for as long as she wanted, however as a *New Zealand* citizen should could only stay there for 3 months max without needing a visa.

Unfortunately renewing the CZ passport is quite complicated and expensive as she would have to travel to the nearest CZ embassy which is in Sydney, Australia. We would like to avoid that if possible.

So the question is - can she stay in Germany for 6 months just on her NZ passport as she's entitled to through the CZ citizenship? Or does she need a German student visa? Or go get the CZ passport renewed regardless the cost?

Comment: She could travel to Germany and get a new Czech passport or ID card after she gets there.

Comment: @phoog not being a German resident, no Czech consulate would be responsible for her. For a study in Baden-Württemberg, non EU Citizens must pay a tuition (everywere elswe it is free).

Comment: You should contact the consulate in Sydney and ask under what conditions (if possible) a passport can be issued/applied for directly inside the Czech Republic.

Comment: @MarkJohnson are the Czechs so strict about residence?  What does a Czech citizen do if her passport or ID is lost or stolen while she is visiting Germany?

Comment: @phoog That is the statement of the Czech Embassy site in Berlin. List of states around Berlin where you must be a resident of. **ist für die in den Bundesländern Berlin, Brandenburg, Bremen, Hamburg, Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Niedersachsen, Hessen, Nordrhein-Westfalen und Schleswig-Holstein wohnenden Antragsteller zuständig.** https://www.mzv.cz/berlin/de/visa_und_konsularinformationen/ortliche_zustandigkeit_konsularischer.html

Comment: @MarkJohnson there must be an exception for Czech citizens in need of emergency travel documents.  Of course, it may be that full passports are not issued in such cases, which if true means that this might be of no help to OP's daughter.  However, in looking (unsuccessfully) for information about this exception, I did see that Czech citizens may get a national ID card from any Czech municipality. An ID card is sufficient to prove Czech nationality to Germany and to the university. Doing that from Germany would be easier than visiting Sydney from New Zealand.

Comment: @phoog does it say that a Czech citizen, who **not** a resident of that municipality, will also be issued with a ID?

Comment: @phoog Appling for a passport from inside the Czech Republic should be possible, thus the question. The Sydney Consulate does not issue ID's, based on a statement on their site. So it looks as that is not possible foreign residing Czechs.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes, though I failed to notice that it must be any municipality "with extended powers." https://www.mzv.cz/brussels/cz/konzularni_a_vizovy_usek/cestovni_doklady/obcansky_prukaz.html. Partial machine translation: A citizen can apply for an identity card at any municipal authority of a municipality with extended powers, in the capital city of Prague at any authority of the Prague 1 to 22 district . As of 1 January 2016, the competence for issuing an identity card has been changed (local jurisdiction has been revoked according to the citizen's permanent residence).

Comment: @phoog that looks promising. Then both a passport and id could be applied for. She must have citizenship certificate which may possibly be issued without going to Sydney (or from a honoury consulte in New Zealand).

Answer (score 7):

- She can't get a student visa. She would be asked to disclose all her current and past citizenships, and once she mentions the current Czech one she is no longer eligible.
- Since NZ is an Annex II country, she could arrive visa-free on her NZ passport and sort things out in Germany. That would leave an entry stamp with no matching exit in the passport, but the same 'incomplete' travel history pattern applies to anyone who gains an EU citizenship while in the Schengen area.
  Problem I: The university might not enroll her while her status is unclear.
  Problem II: Getting the passport might take more than 90 days. (I doubt that ...)
- She could ask at an EU embassy in NZ for consular aid in getting home, i.e. temporary travel papers. That rule is more intended for tourists who get their papers stolen, however.

Comment: Thanks @o.m. I asked the Czech embassy in Sydney and they advised to contact the German embassy directly to figure out what to do as without any valid (non-expired) Czech ID my daughter can't prove her current Czech citizenship and hence will be treated as a New Zealand citizen upon arrival to Germany. Will see what the Germans say.